# Javamail synchronization when opening mailbox, reading existing and starting MessageCountListener

Tags: java, synchronization, jakarta-mail

It seems to me there is no bullet-proof way to open an IMAP mailbox with Javamail, read the existing unread messages and add a [`MessageChangedListener`](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/event/MessageCountListener.html) event listener to read subsequent new arrivals.

The app I am writing must process each message once only, and should never miss any emails.

This is the listener:

```
public class EmailListener implements MessageCountListener {

    private final IncomingEmailProcessor processor;

    @Override
    public void messagesAdded(final MessageCountEvent event) {
        for (Message email : event.getMessages()) {
                processor.process(email);
        }
    }
}
```

If I add the listener first and then grab all the unread messages like this:

```
Session session = javax.mail.Session.getInstance(imapProperties);
store = (IMAPStore) session.getStore(imapProtocol);
store.connect(imapHost, imapUser, imapPassword);
inbox = (IMAPFolder) store.getFolder("INBOX");
inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
inbox.addMessageCountListener(emailListener);
Message messages[] = inbox.search(
    new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false));
for (Message message : messages) {
    processor.process(message);
}
while (inbox.isOpen()) {
    inbox.idle();
}
```

then there is a chance that a new email will arrive between starting the listener and getting the unread messages, and it would be read twice.

If I change it around and add the listener after getting the unread messages from the search, then there is a chance that a new email will arrive after getting the unread messages but before the listener is added, so it would get missed!

Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the folder, process all the messages in the folder, and check whether new messages have arrived (the message count has increased).  If so, loop.  If not, add the listener, then wait for new messages (e.g., by calling the idle method).

Part of the key to understanding how this works is understanding when the server is allowed to notify the client of new messages, and when JavaMail will see those notifications.  Between getting the number of messages and adding the listener JavaMail won't see any notifications of new messages.  By the time you do an operation that will allow JavaMail to see the notification, the listener will be in place.

The JavaMail FAQ includes a [code example](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#addlistener).

Comment: I just searched the javamail website for documentation on this to link to from my own documentation, but I couldn't find anything. Is there anything out there I can link to?

Comment: No, sorry, although much of it is derived from the way the IMAP protocol works and when it's allowed to notify clients of new messages.  This isn't exactly a _frequently_ asked question, but perhaps I should add it to the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html).

Comment: FYI, I finally added this to the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#addlistener), including a code example.

Comment: I see a weird issue, I am receiving the EXISTS notification on new Emails landing in my mailServer, which I can see in debug logs but the addMessageCountListener is never called @BillShannon. Any idea?

Comment: @Shamik  Is this a new issue?  What mail server are you using?  Maybe create a new post with the details, including the JavaMail debug output?

Comment: Thanks for your response @BillShannon, I was able to solve this one. Bug in my code.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. This is what I worked out based off of Bill's answer (for those who are looking for a complete example) :

```
 public static void loadUnreadEmails() throws MessagingException, IOException, SQLException {

    Store store = null;
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
    try {

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
        store = session.getStore();
        store.connect("imap.gmail.com", EMAIL_ID,
                EMAIL_PASSWORD);
        Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
        inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
        int msgCount;
        do {//go through all the unread emails in the inbox at least once
            msgCount = inbox.getMessageCount();//set how many messages are in the inbox when the array is created
            // Fetch unseen messages from inbox folder
            javax.mail.Message[] messages = inbox.search(
                    new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false));
            for (javax.mail.Message msg : messages) {
                //process emails here
                processEmail(msg);
            }
            //if a new message came in while reading the messages start the loop over and get all unread messages    
        } while (inbox.getMessageCount() != msgCount);
        //add listener
        inbox.addMessageCountListener(new MessageCountAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void messagesAdded(MessageCountEvent ev) {
                javax.mail.Message[] messages = ev.getMessages();
                for (javax.mail.Message msg : messages) {
                    //process emails here
                    processEmail(msg);
                }
            }
        });
        // wait for new messages
        while (inbox.isOpen()) {                
            //every 25 minutes poke the server with a inbox.getMessageCount() to keep the connection active/open
            ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
            final Runnable pokeInbox = () -> {
                try {
                    inbox.getMessageCount();
                } catch (MessagingException ex) {
                    //nothing doin'
                }
            };
            scheduler.schedule(pokeInbox, 25, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            ((IMAPFolder) inbox).idle();
        }
    } catch (FolderClosedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("error connection was dropped");
        if (store != null) {
            store.close();
        }
        loadUnreadEmails();//restarts listening for email if the connection times out
    } finally {
        if (store != null) {
            store.close();
        }
    }
}
```